# finding a number is prime or not

Tags: c++, primes

the code is showing wrong results...it is showing 15,21 and many other odd numbers as prime but they are not...how to fix the problem?..what code should I write in main section[inside int main()]?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define M 1000000
bool marked[M];



bool sieve(int n)
{
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        if (marked[i] == false)
        {
            for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i + i)
            {
                marked[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return false;
    if (n == 2)
        return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    return marked[n] == false;
}
int main()
{
    int i,j,k,n,m;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin>>m;
        if(isPrime(m))
            cout<<"prime"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"N"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Is the wrong answer coming due to not properly using or calling functions?.....in this case what should be done.....

Comment: It seems that the intent of the `sieve()` function is to find all the primes. Can you point your finger at the exact line in the shown code that calls this function, and explain exactly when you expect this function to get called, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that, since you never call the `sieve` function, your `marked` array never gets filled. Since `marked` is not dynamically allocated, it is zeroed out within your program. Hence, in your `isPrime` function, all odd numbers will cascade through your `if` statements and then hit the part where `marked[n] == false` which would return true since `marked[n]` is 0 for all of its entries, which is equivalent to the boolean `false`.

You might want to figure out where it would be best to run the `sieve` function.

Comment: then how should be the code?...can you please write down the code?

Comment: You should include a call to the `sieve` function. From the code you have, it might be best to include it on the line after `cin >> n;`, something like `sieve(n);`.

Comment: Also do look at Dmitry's answer mentioning an issue with your increment

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong increment here:

```
for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i + i)
```

You need to increase `j` by `i`, but you actually increase in by `2*i`. Anyway I agree with the previous answer that you never call `sieve`.